# Irreducibility criterion unramified principal series

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with maximal split torus $T_s$, Borel subgroup $B = TN$ and Weyl group $W(G,T_s)$. Let us consider the $\mathbb{Q}_p-$points of $G$ and $B = TN$ that we will also denote by $G$ and $B = TN$. Given $\xi:\;T\to\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ an unramified character we define the normalized induction $\mathrm{Ind}_{B}^{G}\xi$ as the space of smooth functions $f:\;G\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(bgk) = \delta^{1/2}_B(b)\xi(b)f(g)$. For regular characters, i.e. $\xi$ such that $\mathrm{Stab}_{W(G,T_s)}\xi = id$, Casselman gave a if only if criterion for the irreducibility of $\mathrm{Ind}_{B}^{G}\xi$ in prop. 3.5, (b), p. 401, "The unramified principal series of p-adic groups. I. The spherical function". Is there an equivalent result when we remove the hypothesis of the regular character?

If we suppose that the character $\xi$ is unitary, we know that $\xi$ regular implies that $\mathrm{Ind}_{B}^{G}\xi$ is irreducible. Are there results in the other direction?

Comment: By "a topological reductive group" I think you actually mean "a reductive algebraic group over a nonarchimedean local field".

Comment: By the way, how exactly does $W(G, T_s)$ act on characters of $T$ if $T_s \ne T$?

Comment: Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. The group $W(G,T_s) \simeq N_{G}(T_s)/T$. The unramified characters satisfy that $\mathrm{Hom}(T(\mathbb{Q}_p)/T(\mathbb{Z}_p),\mathbb{C}^{\times}) \simeq X^{\bullet}(T)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{C}$, where $X^{\bullet}(T)$ are the rationals characters of the algebraic torus $T$. Given $\xi$ an unramified character of $T(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and $w\in W(G,T_s)$, then $w\cdot\xi(\cdot) = \xi(x^{-1}\cdot x)$ where $x$ is a representative for $w$ in the quotient $N_{G}(T_s)/T$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment about the reductive group, I will correct my question.

Comment: Your definition of $W(G, T_s)$ seems to depend on $T$ (which is not part of the data); I think $N_G(T_s) / Z_G(T_s)$ is the usual definition. For your definition of the action on characters, you seem to be implicitly assuming that $w$ has a representative that normalises $T$ (not just $T_s$); and I don't see anything in the setup that guarantees this.

Comment: Are you sure you want $G$ to be over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $T_s$ a maximal $\mathbb{Q}$-split torus, here? I wonder if it is a typo for $\mathbb{Q}_p$. (It does matter, because a maximal $\mathbb{Q}$-split torus will not necessarily be a maximal $\mathbb{Q}_p$-split torus; it's entirely possible, with your setup, for $G$ to be split over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ but $T_s = \{1\}$, so the Weyl group is the trivial group.

Comment: I just took the definition in "THEORY OF ADMISSIBLE REPRESENTATIONS" Casselman , p. 11. Maybe I misunderstood something. The pair $(G,T_s)$ defines a reduced root datum $\Delta$. Let us take $W(G,T_s)$ be the group of reflections of the roots of $\Delta$. If $\xi$ is an unramified character of $T(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, we can express it as $\tilde{\xi}\otimes  c$ where $\tilde{\xi}$ is a rational character of $T$ and $c\in \mathbb{C}$. Then given $\omega\in W(G,T_s)$ and $\xi$ an unramified character of $T(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, $\omega\cdot\xi = \omega\tilde{\xi}\otimes c$.

Comment: In the case I have in mind the maximal split torus $T_s$ of $G$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ satisfies that $T_s(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is the maximal split torus of $G(\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: You seem to be a little confused (your last comment is a tautology).

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. What I have in mind is that the maximal split torus $T_s$ of $G$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfies that $T_s(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is the maximal split torus of $G(\mathbb{Q}_p)$.